# Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error: String variable as data validation formula

Tags: vba, validation

So, I'm new to VBA and struggling to get my drop down list to display items in the comma separated variable string I'm using. I want to have each value in a given column  displayed as an option in the drop down list. I'm sure its far from the most efficient way to do this, but I've been looping through each value in the column adding it to string until I reach the first blank value. I've confirmed that the variable FilterListString is being populated with the values that I want it to in the correct format, but when I pass it as the formula for validation it bugs out. How do I fix this?

Thank you!

```
   If FilterColumn.Value <> "" Then
    Do While Not IsEmpty(FilterColumn) 'Loop through values in the Filter column until blank
        FilterListString = FilterListString & "," & FilterColumn.Value ' Supplement the Formula String
        Set FilterColumn = FilterColumn.Offset(1, 0) 'Move down Row
    Loop
Else
    FilterListString = " " 'If inital cell is null set to blank
End If

With Sheets("Report Generation").Range("E" & ColumnNumber + 7).Validation 'Create Drop down List on the cell for filtering
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=FilterListString
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Comment: What is the value of `FilterListString` when it errors?

Comment: An efficient way of trouble-shooting VBA is to single-step through the code until the error occurs, then set a breakpoint at the line before, stop the code and restart. At the breakpoint examine the value of whatever causes the error on the next line. This should give you a clue of what is wrong with the code in that location.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code (with minor updates to make it work on my PC) and it runs as it should. My best guess is that the error has much to do with specific values in your worksheets - either the `FilterColumn` values, or the target validated cell.

If you execute the following code in a new workbook, it should provide the desired result.

```
Option Explicit

Sub a()

    Dim FilterColumn As Range
    Dim FilterListString As String
    Dim ColumnNumber As Integer

    Set FilterColumn = Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    FilterListString = "asd"
    ColumnNumber = 1

    '''   testing values
    Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "qqq"
    Sheets(1).Range("A2").Value = 123
    Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "www"

    If FilterColumn.Value <> "" Then
        Do While Not IsEmpty(FilterColumn) 'Loop through values in the Filter column until blank
            FilterListString = FilterListString & "," & FilterColumn.Value ' Supplement the Formula String
            Set FilterColumn = FilterColumn.Offset(1, 0) 'Move down Row
        Loop
    Else
        FilterListString = " " 'If inital cell is null set to blank
    End If

    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count < 2 Then
        Worksheets.Add
    End If

    With Sheets(2).Range("E" & ColumnNumber + 7).Validation 'Create Drop down List on the cell for filtering
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=FilterListString
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: So I tried it again today on my laptop and it all of a sudden works using the same inputs that were failing before.... Do you know what cell or range values could cause this issue?